# How to test any element in a row of a 3D array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, 3d

So I have a 7x7x7 array in C# and I am only wanting it to check the x and z values of the array with a sort of "any" for the y. right now my code is.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 7; x++)
            {

                if(MyArray[x, any , z] == true)
                {

                }

            }


        }
```

Is there a sort of catch all I can use for y, because I don't really want to slow down the process by another factor of 7 by adding another for loop.

Answer (score 0):

use linq

if elements type of your array is Boolean something like exp below
for another type you can change statement in 'All' method to check

```
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < 7; x++)
    {
        if (MyArray[x].All(y => y[z]))
        {

        }
    }
}
```